# Magento : Mass update to 'use default value'

Tags: magento

I need to set a couple hundred products attributes to 'use default' value within a certain store view. How can I do this?

Also, due to the reason that I have more than two storeviews, the method of setting general attributes to 'global' and then back to 'normal' is inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this Link should help you: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/55480/

In the second comment you can see how to set the store ID for your catalog.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(2)
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price');

foreach($products as $p) {
    // ...
    $p->setPrice($price);
    $p->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, later this evening, to modify the script according to my needs and see if it works the way I want.

Comment: `setData()` was the function I was needing and your answer led me to it. Thanks.